# to print the result in two tables

Tags: matrix, printing

I have this code

```
 mat = ( {
    {7, 6},
    {2, 4}
   } );
Row@{"Max ", 
  Grid[mat, 
   Background -> {Automatic, Automatic, 
     Table[{n, Last@Ordering[mat[[n]]]} -> Red, {n, Length@mat}]}, 
   Frame -> All, ItemSize -> {3, 2}]}
```

As a result, this code shows the maximum in each row. I want to ask is it possible to show me the result separately. For example in the first table to show me that the maximum in the first row is 7 and in the second table show me that the maximum of the second row is 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mat = RandomInteger[10, {5, 4}];

Manipulate[
 Row@{"Max by row ",
   Grid[mat,
    Background -> {Automatic, 
      Automatic, {row, Last@Ordering[mat[[row]]]} -> Red},
    Frame -> All,
    ItemSize -> {3, 2}]},
 {{row, 1}, Range[Length@mat]}]
```

[image]

Compare with

```
Max /@ mat

(* {10, 9, 5, 6, 9} *)
```

**EDIT** To find the [`Max`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Max.html) by column use [`Transpose`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Transpose.html).

```
Max /@ Transpose@mat

(* {9, 9, 10, 8} *)

Manipulate[
 Module[{trans = Transpose@mat},
  Row@{"Max by column ",
    Grid[mat, Background -> {Automatic, Automatic,
       {Last@Ordering[trans[[col]]], col} -> Red},
     Frame -> All,
     ItemSize -> {3, 2}]}], {{col, 1, "column"}, 
  Range[Length@mat[[1]]]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but if possible, I would prefer it to be without  manipulate. Because after dividing the result into two tables each one of them will use it in another code.I need a code that prints max in the first row and code for the second row. But I do not think how to divide it.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you are trying to accomplish. If you make it clearer, there is likely a better way to accomplish it than printing multiple tables that are just intermediate steps.

Comment: I have managed to solve the problem with your variation. Thank you. To find the maximum in each column what should i change in the code? I tried several things but did not want to color them.